# aws-cli only return certain fields

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

Given this example of `aws-cli` command

```
aws rds describe-db-cluster-snapshots
```

I returns a list of objects with fields.

I only want to display the fields: `"SnapshotCreateTime"` and `"DBClusterIdentifier"`

How do I do this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

AWS CLI provides built-in output filtering capabilities with the `--query` option.

```
aws rds describe-db-cluster-snapshots --query 'DBClusterSnapshots[*].[SnapshotCreateTime,DBClusterIdentifier]'
```

The above will work if your **AWS CLI**  configured in the same region and have single AWS CLI profile. If AWS CLI configured in a different region and different profile then you can use below command.

```
 aws rds describe-db-cluster-snapshots --query 'DBClusterSnapshots[*].[SnapshotCreateTime,DBClusterIdentifier]' --region us-west-2 --profile test
```

[cli-usage-output](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-usage-output.html)